# Composer install failed with PEAR

Tags: php, composer-php, magento2, php-7.1, code-migration

I am working in Magento 2 code migration tool, there I am stucked at composer install.

Error is as below :-
In RemoteFilesystem.php line 515:

The "https://pear.php.net/get/Archive_Tar-1.4.3.tgz" file could not be downloaded: Peer certificate CN=`mail.cweiske.de' did not match expected CN=`pear.php.net'
  Failed to enable crypto
  failed to open stream: operation failed

How overcome from this error ?

Comment: Pear is apparently down for the moment. Not sure how long its been down for, or how long it will be down for. Seems there was a breach. Though your specific issue is that the SSL cert doesn't match the domain, this probably has something to do with it.

Comment: [Something similar](https://blog.flowl.info/2015/pear-certificate-invalid-due-to-servercrash/) seems to have happened in 2015. The replacement certificate seems to be a default fallback for the intermediate/backup servers

Comment: https://twitter.com/pear/status/1086634389465956352 3 days and counting it seems.